# Adding Ajax jQuery reference in Web API

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

In a project of Web API in Visual Studio I want to call `POST` method with jQuery

My model is

```
public class Book
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

My `Post` Method

```
public void Post(List<Book> books)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("BookStore");
            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                var collection = db.GetCollection<Book>("BookCollection");
                collection.Save(book);
            }
        }
```

My script

```
<script>
    var books = [
                { "Id": 1, "Title": "My Book 1"},
                { "Id": 2, "Title": "My Book 2" },
                { "Id": 3, "Title": "My Book 3" },
                { "Id": 4, "Title": "My Book 4" },
                { "Id": 5, "Title": "My Book 5" },
                { "Id": 6, "Title": "My Book 6" }
    ];        var postString = JSON.stringify(books);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "http://localhost:10746/api/values",
        data: postString,
        success: function () {
            alert(postString);
        }
    });

</script>
```

it didn't work. Am I missing any reference?

Comment: Your model is defined as `Id` - your JS list has `ID` defined. Also, no need to stringify your data before posting - it should map back fine. And can you define "didnt work"? (errors in the console? what's the status of the request?)

Comment: It should create a database in MongoDB. @tymeJV

Comment: And also this ajax calling did not call the Post method

Comment: What's the error are you getting, can you verify in `fiddler` or `firebug`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried shortening your URL to relative path?

You could be falling foul of this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

If there is any differentiation in your ports it could be seen as a cross domain request which most servers would block as default.